# Recuperar link ao usar o click() do selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Preciso recuperar o endereço da url ao clicar no link, estou usando o selenium com `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")`

Meu código atual:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Excel')
for link in links:
    link.click()
```

tentei usar o `driver.current_url` mas como da um click se eu usar a renderização do navegador ele abre uma nova aba e em seguida já fecha.

A ideia é fazer download de vários arquivos mas como estou usando o headless pelo que pesquisei a melhor opção seria usar um `driver.get` diretamente na URL ao clicar no link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode pegar o atributo da tag que contém o link, como no exemplo:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Excel')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Maravilha deu certo, e eu quebrando a cabeça.